# index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 in matrix

Tags: python, numpy

So his code was for a 3xN dimensional matrix where the past present and future were the 3 rows. I have changed it to a one dimensional array for faster computation. where am I going wrong

```
psi_past_real = np.zeros((1,domain)) #  real part 3xN matrix 
psi_past_imaginary = np.zeros((1,domain))
psi_present_real = np.zeros((1,domain))
psi_present_imaginary = np.zeros((1,domain)) 
psi_future_real = np.zeros((1,domain))
psi_future_imaginary = np.zeros((1,domain))
psi_probability = np.zeros(domain,)   # Probability


xn = range(1,domain/2)
x = X[xn]/dx    #  Normalized position coordinate
gg = Gaussian(x,x0,sigma)
cx = np.cos(k0*x)
sx = np.sin(k0*x)
psi_present_real[xn] = cx*gg
psi_present_imaginary[xn] = sx*gg
psi_past_real[xn] = cx*gg
psi_past_imaginary[xn] = sx*gg
```

the gaussian function is

```
def Gaussian(x,t,sigma):
    np.exp(-(x-t)**2/(2*sigma**2))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Spyder 2.7.app/Contents/Resources/lib/python2.7/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 586, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/kabirthakur/Desktop/untitled1.py", line 73, in <module>
    psi_present_real[xn] = cx*gg
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: Please provide a full traceback.

Comment: Welcome to SO: Please take the [tour] and read [MCVE].

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Done

Comment: Redeclare all your variables like this: `psi_... = np.zeros(domain, )`

Answer (score 1):

The shape of psi_present_real is (1, domain). If you want to index it by the second coordinate, you need to indicate this by using a colon in the first coordinate:

```
psi_present_real[:, xn] = cx*gg
```